# Search Bar doesn't disappear after segue to new ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

`Search Bar` doesn't want to disapper after segue to new `ViewController`. I create `search bar` doing it:

```
    self.searchBar = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchBar.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchBar.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false


    self.navigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar.searchBar
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

for segue to new `View Controller` from `TableViewController`I use this function:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ContentViewCOntroller", sender: self)       
}
```

More details in this pictures:

[First TableController where I search data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKxvO.jpg)

[Second ViewControler with SearchBar, which schould disaper, but it still exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Xno.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `searchBar.active = false` just before you perform the segue. (Or in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: I spent 3 hours searching for an answer to address this issue, finally I found yours! Thank you so much!!